# error while running hello world app

Tags: android-emulator

I installed android SDk and copy the adb.exe and AdbWinApi.dll file into tool directory.

when I run my hello world app I am getting below error.

plz help to get rid of this error and get emulator up and running.

thanks in advance.

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\TitaniumProjects\damosh\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.7.1\android\builder.py emulator damosh C:\Android\android-sdk C:\TitaniumProjects\damosh ssd 7 WXGA
[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment
[DEBUG] From: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe
[DEBUG] SDCard: C:\Users\suchi\.titanium\android2.sdcard
[DEBUG] AVD ID: 7
[DEBUG] AVD Skin: WXGA
[DEBUG] SDK: C:\Android\android-sdk
[DEBUG] C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[DEBUG] **C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd titanium_7_WXGA -port 5560 -sdcard C:\Users\suchi\.titanium\android2.sdcard -logcat '*:d *' -no-boot-anim -partition-size 128 invalid command-line parameter: *'.**
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
[DEBUG] signal caught: 3
[DEBUG] calling emulator kill on 5300
ERROR: The process "5300" not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are several suggestion on Appcelerator's site. Did you tried them?

Link: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125198/problem-with-emulator-in-android
Link: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123477/problem-with-space-in-filename#answer-214976

I tried them all but none of them worked for me. What I did:

Go to Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Titanium Studio -> Titanium:
- make sure your android SDK path does not contain any white spaces.
- make sure you titanium path also does not contain any white spaces
(replace the with ~ or ~1 or ~2 after the sixth character.)

I saw that the path to my SD card contained a white space:

```
[DEBUG] SDCard: 'C:\Users\Adis Corovic\.titanium\android2.sdcard'
```

So I opened the builder.py:

```
C:\Users\Adis Corovic\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.7.2\android\builder.py
```

On line 400 I changed this:

```
self.sdcard
```

into this:

```
"'" + self.sdcard.replace("Adis Corovic", "AdisCo~1") + "'",
```

Good luck!